# Spring boot Security Redirecting from error page to login page In case of authentication failure

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have configured spring security for my web application, Implemented custom authentication handler to authenticate the user details.

Its working as expected when authentication is success ,when authentication fails its invoking custom authentication failure handler redirecting error page(in my case login page with error message) after that again it's redirecting to login page(without message)

Below is my configuration (Let me know what's wrong here)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Autowired
    private AuthSuccessHandler authHandler;
    @Autowired
    private AuthFailureHandler authFailureHandler;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/resources/**","/rest/**")
             .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
             .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/login")
             .successHandler(authHandler)
             .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
             .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
             .permitAll()
             .and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)  {

        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }
}

Success Handler

@Component
public class AuthSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
    @Override
    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/home");
    }
}


Failure Handler

@Component
public class AuthFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler{

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("AuthFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure()");
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/login?msg=Bad Credentials");
    }
}


Custom Authentication Provider 

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider
{
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException    {

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        String username = (String)token.getPrincipal();
        String password = (String) token.getCredentials(); // retrieve the password 
        System.out.println("username="+username+" password="+password);
        flag = //autheticate logic 
        if(flag) {
                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ONE"));
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_TWO"));
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, authorities);
           }
        else
        throw new BadCredentialsException("401");
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> object) {
        return object.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}

Controller :
Below is the controller configuration

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(name="msg",required=false) String message)
     {
            System.out.println("HomeController.login()"+message);
            return new ModelAndView("login","message",message);
    }
```

login.jsp

```
<form id='loginForm'  method='GET' action='./login'>
   <div class="login">
      <div id='errorMsg' class="hide alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong><i class='fa fa-warning'></i>
         <span id='errorTitle'></span></strong><span id='errorText'></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for='txtUserName' class="UsernamePassword">Username:</label>
         <input name="username" type="email" class="form-control" value="" id="txtUserName" maxlength="100" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for='txtPassword' class="UsernamePassword">Password:</label>
         <input value='' name="password" class="form-control" type="password" id="txtPassword" maxlength="100" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">                      
         <label>
         <input checked type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" id="checkboxRememberMe"/> Remember My Information
         </label>
      </div>
      <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
         <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <p>Invalid username and password.</p>
         </div>
      </c:if>
      <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
         <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>You have been logged out successfully.</p>
         </div>
      </c:if>
      <div>
         <p>${message}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
         <button id="btnLogin" class="btnBlue" style='width:100% !important' type='submit'>Login</button>
      </div>
      <div class="usernamePassword">
         <a href="#" onclick='forgotPassword()'>I forgot my username/password</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really important that the "/login?msg=Bad Credentials" is added to an authorizeRequests() section otherwise the controller won't pick up the error parameter.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/resources/**","/rest/**,/login*").permitAll()
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
             .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/login")
             .successHandler(authHandler)
             .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
             .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
             .permitAll()
             .and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this config :

```
.formLogin()
.loginPage("/login")
.failureUrl("/login?error")
```

Comment: Tried but same issue its invoking controller with error message after that its invoking login controller with no message.From logs HomeController.login()bad credentials                                                                                 HomeController.login()null    . is there anything wrong in  the home controller config